# Measure heap growth accurately

Tags: go, heap-memory

I am trying to measure the evolution of the number of heap-allocated objects before and after I call a function. I am forcing runtime.GC() and using runtime.ReadMemStats to measure the number of heap objects I have before and after.

The problem I have is that I *sometimes* see unexpected heap growth. And it is different after each run.

A simple example below, where I would always expect to see a zero heap-objects growth.

https://go.dev/play/p/FBWfXQHClaG

```
var mem1_before, mem2_before, mem1_after, mem2_after runtime.MemStats

func measure_nothing(before, after *runtime.MemStats) {
    runtime.GC()
    runtime.ReadMemStats(before)

    runtime.GC()
    runtime.ReadMemStats(after)
}

func main() {
    measure_nothing(&mem1_before, &mem1_after)
    measure_nothing(&mem2_before, &mem2_after)

    log.Printf("HeapObjects diff = %d", int64(mem1_after.HeapObjects-mem1_before.HeapObjects))
    log.Printf("HeapAlloc diff %d", int64(mem1_after.HeapAlloc-mem1_before.HeapAlloc))

    log.Printf("HeapObjects diff = %d", int64(mem2_after.HeapObjects-mem2_before.HeapObjects))
    log.Printf("HeapAlloc diff %d", int64(mem2_after.HeapAlloc-mem2_before.HeapAlloc))
}
```

Sample output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 HeapObjects diff = 0
2009/11/10 23:00:00 HeapAlloc diff 0
2009/11/10 23:00:00 HeapObjects diff = 4
2009/11/10 23:00:00 HeapAlloc diff 1864
```

Is what I'm trying to do unpractical? I assume the runtime is doing things that allocate/free heap-memory. Can I tell it to stop to make my measurements? (this is for a test checking for memory leaks, not production code)

Comment: Why don't you use the testing framework to measure this? Benchmarking reports allocations / op and also bytes / op, multiply them to get the heap difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't predict what garbage collection and reading all the memory stats require in the background. Calling those to calculate memory allocations and usage is not a reliable way.

Luckily for us, Go's [testing framework](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) can monitor and calculate memory usage.

So what you should do is write a benchmark function and let the testing framework do its job to report memory allocations and usage.

Let's assume we want to measure this `foo()` function:

```
var x []int64

func foo(allocs, size int) {
    for i := 0; i < allocs; i++ {
        x = make([]int64, size)
    }
}
```

All it does is allocate a slice of the given `size`, and it does this with the given number of times (`allocs`).

Let's write benchmarking functions for different scenarios:

```
func BenchmarkFoo_0_0(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        foo(0, 0)
    }
}

func BenchmarkFoo_1_1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        foo(1, 1)
    }
}

func BenchmarkFoo_2_2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        foo(2, 2)
    }
}
```

Running the benchmark with `go test -bench . -benchmem`, the output is:

```
BenchmarkFoo_0_0-8   1000000000      0.3204 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkFoo_1_1-8   67101626       16.58 ns/op      8 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFoo_2_2-8   27375050       42.42 ns/op     32 B/op    2 allocs/op
```

As you can see, the allocations per function call is the same what we pass as the `allocs` argument. The allocated memory is the expected `allocs * size * 8 bytes`.

Note that the reported allocations per op is an integer value (it's the result of an integer division), so if the benchmarked function only occasionally allocates, it might not be reported in the integer result. For details, see [Output from benchmem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255211/output-from-benchmem/56256892#56256892).

Like in this example:

```
var x []int64

func bar() {
    if rand.Float64() < 0.3 {
        x = make([]int64, 10)
    }
}
```

This `bar()` function does 1 allocation with *30% probability* (and none with *70% probability*), which means on *average* it does 0.3 allocations. Benchmarking it:

```
func BenchmarkBar(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bar()
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
BenchmarkBar-8   38514928       29.60 ns/op    24 B/op     0 allocs/op
```

We can see there is 24 bytes allocation (0.3 * 10 * 8 bytes), which is correct, but the reported allocations per op is 0.

Luckily for us, we can also benchmark a function from our main app using the [`testing.Benchmark()`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#Benchmark) function. It returns a [`testing.BenchmarkResult`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#BenchmarkResult) including all details about memory usage. We have access to the total number of allocations and to the number of iterations, so we can calculate allocations per op using floating point numbers:

```
func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    tr := testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkBar)
    fmt.Println("Allocs/op", tr.AllocsPerOp())
    fmt.Println("B/op", tr.AllocedBytesPerOp())

    fmt.Println("Precise allocs/op:", float64(tr.MemAllocs)/float64(tr.N))
}
```

This will output:

```
Allocs/op 0
B/op 24
Precise allocs/op: 0.3000516369276302
```

We can see the expected ~0.3 allocations per op.

Now if we go ahead and benchmark your `measure_nothing()` function:

```
func BenchmarkNothing(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        measure_nothing(&mem1_before, &mem1_after)
    }
}
```

We get this output:

```
Allocs/op 0
B/op 11
Precise allocs/op: 0.12182030338389732
```

As you can see, running the garbage collector twice and reading memory stats twice occasionally needs allocation (~1 out of 10 calls: 0.12 times on average).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately, it didn't really help me. The `allocs/op` is a rounded number of allocations. So it "hides" the spurious heap allocation I wanted to trace. I tried to play with testing.AllocsPerRun, which has the same problem (even if it returns a float, it is rounded!)

So I still don't know where do the allocations come from. Tried pprof (elides small objects), alloctrace=1 (not sure what to do with 500M of stack traces), and couldn't trace it.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not supposed to measure this kind of stuff over a single run. If the standard go code do these kinds of measurements over thousands of runs, it's probably for a good reason.

Comment: @rtur I edited the answer to show how you can catch spurious allocations.